# Use LDAP to authenticate oracle database users

Tags: active-directory, ldap, oracle, oracle-11g

I have Oracle Database 11g set up in few locations in either pure Linux/OpenLDAP, Samba/OpenLDAP environment and a full-blown Windows/AD environment.
The applications that will be using those databases will ask the user for domain password and connect using the provided user/password pair to the database.

From that, I think that the best solution would be to proxy the authentication from the database to the LDAP, if the user can authenticate to LDAP, he can access the database.

It won't be a problem if I have to manually define all users that can connect to database beforehand. It needs to deny access if the LDAP password is incorrect or the LDAP account is locked.

How to configure the Oracle Database 11g to use LDAP for authentication?
Can this be done in portable manner, working with AD and regular LDAP servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a this problem has been solved on Database Administrators: [Can I use OpenLDAP to Authenticate users in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/336/can-i-use-openldap-to-authenticate-users-in-oracle)